# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver running jar file

Tags: java, mysql, jar

I have a jar file which runs perfect in dis folder but when I copy it to desktop and run in from cmd I got

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I already include mysql library as shown below
[image]

[image]

any idea please?

Comment: Please attach the jar running command. You should attach external library like :      `java -classpath /path/to/jdbc -jar PayRoll_3.jar`

Comment: add mysql jar to classpath as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here, wish it would be useful for other people
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-139904.html